# Signaling the main thread asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading

I may be going about this all wrong but I'm stuck. I have a GUI application that spawns a separate thread that downloads a bunch of data from a server. When this download thread is finished I want it to send a signal to the main thread so that it knows it can now display the downloaded data.

I've tried calling Invoke (from my main form) to call a delegate to do the display work, but this blocks my downloader thread until its finished. I kind of want to just do a BeginInvoke without an EndInvoke but I know its not proper to do so.

Comment: Can you post some code? The Control.Invoke(delegate) should work just fine

Comment: BeginInvoke does not need an EndInvoke.  I use BeginInvoke all the time without EndInvoke.

Comment: Check also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: @Casperah `Control.BeginInvoke` does not need an `EndInvoke` call - but "BeginInvoke" in general may - when using the original asynchronous pattern, the pattern specifies that all calls to BeginInvoke *must* call their appropriate `EndInvoke`, which is probably where Frank got this idea...

Comment: The msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx states "You can call EndInvoke to retrieve the return value from the delegate, if neccesary, but this is not required."

Comment: @ReedCopsey that's precisely right. I automatically assumed that all `BeginInvoke`s were made alike. Thanks Reed and Casperah for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options.

My personal favorite is to use the TPL.  On your UI thread, you can make a `TaskFactory`, like so:

```
// Given:
// TaskFactory uiFactory;

uiFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Then, in your background task, you can just create a `Task` to update your UI:

```
var task = uiFactory.StartNew( () => UpdateUserInterface(data));
```

This will marshal to the UI thread correctly, similar to a `BeginInvoke` call.  If you need to block, you can call `task.Wait()` (or `task.Result` if the Update method returns a value).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the kind of thing I've been looking for. Having to pass an instance of a `Control` around so you can `Invoke` on it all of the time seemed wrong to me.

Comment: @FrankWeindel The nice thing about this is it works with ANY UI framework, and even with things like WCF's synchronization context.  You aren't tied to a specific UI framework (WPF, Silverlight, WinForms, etc) when using the TPL, and it transitions great to C# 5's async, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- For WinForms use the [Control.BeginInvoke method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx).
- For WPF use the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604730%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- "The TPL has other schedulers in addition to the default one and also allows you to create custom schedulers. One of the schedulers that TPL provides is based on the current synchronization context, and it can be used to ensure that my task executes on the UI thread." ([Source article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx)):

  ```
  var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(),
      result =>
      {
          var time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
          label1.Content += time.ToString();
      }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, ui);
  ```

  In the case with download scenario, `.ContinueWith()` continuation would be appropriate.